# Error Creating record in MySQL: "Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a registration file and I used this code for creating it:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $res= $conn->prepare("Insert into user (Name,Email,user_name,password)Values (:name,:email,:user,md5(:pass))");
    $res->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $res->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $res->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $res->bindParam(':pass', $pass);

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username =$_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $res->execute();

    if ($res==TRUE) {
        echo 'Registered successfully';
    } else {
        echo 'There was some error.';
    }      
}    
?>
```

But I get this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_name' cannot be
>   null'

Here is the **HTML** part of my code.

```
 <body>
        <form action="Registration.php" method="post" >
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email"  /><br>
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="user" /><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>                
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SignUp!"/>
        </form>       
    </body>
```

Comment: $username !== $user..... `$res->bindParam(':user', $user);` and `$username =$_POST['user'];`

Comment: You're going to have a similar issue with `$password` but it might not yell at you...

Comment: you did change place of parts with post, they must be placed before bind part

Comment: also check user / username and pass / password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Baker's comment is correct and highlights the core problem. You are binding the username to a variable $username, but your SQL statement is looking for $user. Because the $user variable is not set, it is null and violates your database constraints when the SQL statement is executed.

Adjust your code to

```
$user =$_POST['user'];
```

and it should work

Comment: O ya that was such a minor thanks form your keen eyes